# Disable firebase app check for local emulator in angularfire

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire, firebase-app-check

I have this code in my `imports` array in `app.module.ts` to enable app check.
It works fine but I get a new debug token in the console very often.
I have to add this token to the firebase console every time. It's really annoying, is there a way to disable app check for the local emulator?

```
provideAppCheck(() => {
      const appCheck = initializeAppCheck(getApp(), {
        provider: new ReCaptchaV3Provider(environment.appCheck),
        isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true,
      });

      return appCheck;
    }),
```

I get this error in the console too:

```
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

Comment: Are you using `FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN` ? link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/debug-provider#localhost

Comment: yes but I have no idea how to set this in angular using angularfire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just disabled appcheck because the docs are not there

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are calling something like this in you `AppComponent`

```
private appCheck: AppCheck = inject(AppCheck);
```

Something like this might work:

```
private appCheck: AppCheck;

constructor(...){
    ...
    if(!enviroment.deug){
        this.appCheck = inject(AppCheck);
    }
}
```

Comment: well no just the code above in my app.module, the docs aren't really clear but I just want to enable appcheck for my entire app once in 1 place